# Cocoapods page redirecting to github

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I made a new pod and pushed it to trunk. It's appearing in the cocoadocs (http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/KeyboardLayoutHelper/0.0.1/) page, but http://cocoapods.org/pods/KeyboardLayoutHelper is redirecting to github.

The pod is working as expected when installed with `pod install`.

Did I do something wrong or is this something I should submit to issues at cocoapods.org's github page?

**Edit: It's been about a week now, still redirecting to my github.**

My pod is also appearing differently than all others in the cocoapods.org search:

[image]

Comment: It is working now.

Comment: @Sulthan are we looking at the same thing? Still redirecting me

Comment: This is happening again to several pods - https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoadocs.org/issues/519

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It takes some time to create your CocoaPods page if you just published it. Try waiting a day or so.

Comment: Waited a week, nothing changed.

Comment: You may try opening an issue with them similar to this one: https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods.org/issues/265

I experienced the same issue when I created a new Pod, but it updated over time - they may have just done a batch update at that time.

Comment: Okay, seems like I should be taking this discussion to their github page. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After waiting 24 hours of my first version,
I just tried to release new version i.e. 1.0.1 & It's published within few minutes. :)

For new version i did below-

- Modified .podspec file with   s.version          = '1.0.1'
- pod lib lint
- echo "3.0" >> .swift-version//optional for my usecase
- pod trunk register xx@Email.com
- pod trunk push JKDropDown.podspec

[image]

& it's Live here https://cocoapods.org/pods/JKDropDown

Answer (score 0):

This happens if documentation of your pod file crashes [appledoc](http://appledoc.gentlebytes.com/appledoc/) or [jazzy](https://github.com/realm/jazzy).Conflict in documentation can lead to redirection. Redeploying will fix issue. Open terminal and hit this command:

```
curl http://207.254.41.223:4567/redeploy/[YOUR-POD-NAME]/latest
```

Comment: Failed to connect to 207.254.41.223 port 4567: Connection refused

Comment: Seems like it was an old issue and after 10 mins I am seeing my update but thanks anyway