# pod trunk push successfully but the CocoaPods link redirect to github

Tags: cocoapods

I created a project and push to CocoaPods successfully:

```
   Congrats

   MyProject (0.1.1) successfully published
   December 6th, 22:50
   https://cocoapods.org/pods/MyProject
   Tell your friends!
```

But unfortunately, when I click the link (https://cocoapods.org/pods/MyProject), it will redirect to my github link (https://github.com/MyUserName/MyProject).

What could be the cause?

**EDIT:**

[image]

Here are all my projects. The last one is linked to github. The other ones have **Expand button** but this one only has some buttons like **Site**, **Docs**, **Spec**. I created all the projects in the same way. But don't know why it's different.

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38154360/cocoapods-page-redirecting-to-github/45305235#45305235