# Cocoapod spec redirects to homepage

Tags: cocoapods

I published my cocoapod spec several weeks ago but accessing it on cocoapods.org still redirects to my homepage.

You can see it redirect by clicking the link here: https://cocoapods.org/?q=csync-swift

Is there something I need to change in my `.podspec`?

Comment: There is some context here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38154360/cocoapods-page-redirecting-to-github