# my pod is not in the list after pod trunk push and success

Tags: cocoapods, podfile

I've just created a pod and push it to the cocoa pods with no error.

```
  Congrats

  xxxxx (0.1.1) successfully published

  July 26th, 15:44

  https://cocoapods.org/pods/xxxx
  Tell your friends!
```

But I can not see it on the list (cocoapods.com)

Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: I tried to release new version & it worked for me - See my answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38154360/cocoapods-page-redirecting-to-github/45305235#45305235   & let me know

Comment: It can take a few days to show up. In the meantime you should still be able to access it via "pod install"